# Error al hacer post de documento en sistema de archivos

Tags: imagen, post, error404

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]Saludo amigos, En mi app hecha con **NextJs v14** he hecho un formulario desde donde el usuario va a cargar una imagen desde su dispositivo, esta imagen ya que serán 2 ó 3 quiero guardarlas en el sistema de archivos, pero al momento de hacer el "post" me da un error y no se guarda, si por favor alguien me ayuda a solucionarlo se los agradezco. les dejo imágenes para que vea mi código y error.

**Componente:** UploadImage

```
import useControl from "@/hooks/useControlProvider";
import React from "react";

const UploadImage = () => {
  const { setFile, file } = useControl();

  return (
    <div className="flex gap-3 items-center">
      <input
        type="file"
        onChange={(e) => {
          setFile(e.target.files[0]);
        }}
      />

      <button
        onClick={async () => {
          if (!file) return;

          const form = new FormData();
          form.set("file", file);

          //Sending file to server
          const res = await fetch("/api/upload/route"
          , {
            method: "POST",
            body: form
          }
          );
          const data = await res.json();
          console.log(data);
        }}
        className="p-2 bg-gray-300 border border-black rounded-xl"
      >
        Upload
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default UploadImage;
```

**Ahora el POST:** pages/api/upload/route

```
export default async function POST(request) {

const data = await request.formData()
console.log(data)

    return new Response(JSON.stringify({
        message: 'upload File'
    }))
}[![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][1]][1]
```

Comment: y que error te da???

Comment: Perdón, ya lo he agregado a la publicación.